# Do I need to recheck luggage in London for a US flight when changing from Eurowings to Lufthansa?

Tags: usa, air-travel, luggage, transit-visas

I have a flight from Germany to the US. I bought my ticket from Egencia as a single purchase. I have a layover in London as I switch from Eurowings to Lufthansa. Do they transfer my luggage or do I need to recheck it? I am asking this to consider whether I need a transit visa.

Comment: I don't think that Lufthansa operates any flights from London to the US.  Is it a codeshare operated by some other airline?

Comment: Also, which airport in London is your connection?

Answer (score 1):

After booking, Egencia sends several e-mails. One of them will be completely capitalized, and it will have your name in the e-mail subject.

This e-mail tells you what exactly has been booked. It has a section starting with "FLIGHT TICKET(S)" that lists all the tickets that have been issued for your itinerary. If there is only one ticket number there, then everything is booked onto one ticket. In this case, your luggage should be tagged through to your final destination. In case of doubt, *ask* the counter staff when doing your bag drop, or, since you appear not to have a citizenship that enables you hassle-free entry to the UK, call Lufthansa.

However, note that you can also book a connection via London that involves two different airports in London. In this case, you will most likely be asked to collect your luggage at your first airport in London and then proceed to the second airport with your luggage. You will need to have entry permission to the UK on such a ticket.

If your port of entry in the US is not your final destination, you will have to carry your luggage through customs and then immediately check it in again at a designated counter. Again, ask about this at the bag drop of the first airport in your connection if you are unsure.

Finally, the said all-capitalized e-mail should have booking references. One of them will be for Lufthansa, and you can view your booking on the Lufthansa.com website. Click on "Book & Manage" and then on "View Booking". Input your record locator and your last name and you will be able to see what flight legs are on your ticket. After verifying that a record locator is valid on the Lufthansa page, you can also use it to call Lufthansa with your baggage transfer question to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

NO, if you booked the fly togehther. If you book both fly extra you must take and check-in again. But you ask the first check-in if he can handle is to forward.

Comment: That is *often* how it works, but do you have evidence that this is how it will work in this particular case?  In particular, how do you know that Egencia has made the purchase as a single ticket, rather than two separate, unconnected, tickets.